# Data show vs data shows

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I have seen “data” used with “show” and with “shows” in the newspaper. For example,

> 1. Data **show** that domestic violence increases when there is a greater unemployment.
> 2. Data **shows** that domestic violence increases when there is a greater unemployment.

Which one is correct?

Please clarify is it grammatically correct to use **shows**  in above sentence.

Comment: There are also very detailed answers on our sister site English Language & Usage: [Is “data” treated as singular or plural in formal contexts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6904/80039)

Comment: You said you saw a sentence in the newspaper, but there are two sentences in your question. Which sentence was in the paper and why do you think it was a mistake?

Comment: @ColleenV both the sentences are there in news paper

Comment: It seems unlikely that the same sentence would be written with two different verbs in a newspaper, so I think I am not understanding you.

Comment: @ColleenV .sorry for my inability to clearly expree.i have seen in a newspaper as data show then i search it in google.Then some reference papers use data shows as well

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I understand what you meant now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Data* is the plural of *datum*, therefore, *show* is correct. But that doesn't mean *shows* is incorrect.

Use of *data* as a mass noun (which is treated as singular, grammatically) is widespread and widely accepted, and is probably the more common usage today.

So I would accept either, and expect to see *shows* more commonly.

Comment: Grr. The OED shows examples of mass-noun _data_ from 1702, only 70 years after its first appearance in English. And yet people still trot out these categorical statements about what is "correct". (It also has _data_ as a singular, with plural _datas_, from 1645)

Comment: @ColinFine, when I said that "show is correct" I didn't intend to imply that "shows" is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, The Photon